# "Expected rolls to get a 6": recursion vs infinite sum

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, markov-chains

For the question of

> How many throws on average to get a $6$ on a dice?

The recursive answer is quoted as $\mathbb{E}[X] = p + q(1 + \mathbb{E}[X])$, where $p = \frac{1}{6}$ and $q = 1 - p$.

I know that this has been explained in other answers but I still do not understand the intuition behind the second term. Would someone be able to explain how one would get to this? Are there any good resources on recursive probabilities that anyone would recommend? I have not come across this in Feller's Intro version 1 book yet.

Also, how would this be expanded to equal the original infinite equation of $$\mathbb{E}[X] = p + 2qp + 3q^2p + 4q^3p + \dots?$$

Because when I expand it just by one recursive step I get $$\mathbb{E}[X] = p + q + q(p + q(1 + \mathbb{E}[X])) = p + q + qp + q^2(1 + \mathbb{E}[X])$$ which seems like it would not equal the original infinite sum. Have I expanded incorrectly?

Thanks.

Comment: You should study Markov Chains for a rigorous explanation. But an intuitive explanation for the second term $q(1+E(X))$ is as follows: if you don't roll a $6$ (with probability $q$), then you've made one ($1$) extra roll and is expected to make $E(X)$ more rolls. The problem with this argument is that it glosses over whether $E(X)$ exists or is finite at all (note: $y=\infty$ also satisfies the equation $y=p+q(1+y)$).

Comment: @BenjaminWang thank you for your answer. I have not come across Markov Chains yet so this is probably why I don't understand (I will have a look at them next). What confuses me is why after rolling a non-6 you would be expected to roll the expected number + 1? Sorry if that's not clear

Comment: Because you have "wasted" a roll, so are starting from scratch.

Comment: Okay I think it makes a bit more sense then, thank you. How come it doesn't seem to expand to the original equation of $p + 2qp + 3q^2p + 4q^3p + ....$ though? Or have I expanded incorrectly? or maybe you can't do this kind of expansion with this kind of equation?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your expansion, which you can simplify to
$$
\mathbb{E}(X)=1+q+q^2\mathbb{E}(X)\ .
$$
Taking this one step further gives
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(X)&=1+q+q^2(1+q\mathbb{E}(X))\\
&=1+q+q^2+q^3\mathbb{E}(X)\  
\end{align}
and you can obviously continue by induction to get
$$
\mathbb{E}(X)=1+q+q^2+\dots+q^n+q^{n+1}\mathbb{E}(X)
$$
for any $\ n\ .$

However you can also rewrite your expansion as
$$
\mathbb{E}(X)=p+2pq+2q^2+q^2\mathbb{E}(X)\  
$$
and taking this one step further gives
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(X)&=p+2pq+2q^2+q^2(1+q\mathbb{E}(X))\\
&=p+2pq+3q^2+q^3\mathbb{E}(X)\\
&=p+2pq+3pq^2+3q^3+q^3\mathbb{E}(X)\ .
\end{align}
Again you can obviously continue by induction to get
$$
\mathbb{E}(X)=p+2pq+\dots+(n+1)pq^n+(n+1)q^{n+1}+q^{n+1}\mathbb{E}(X)\ .
$$
Since both series $\ \sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty q^n\ $ and $\ \sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty (n+1)pq^n $ converge to the same limit, $\ \frac{1}{1-q}=\frac{1}{p}\ ,$ which is also the value of $\ \mathbb{E}(X)\ ,$ there's no inconsistency here.

Comment: Thank you so much! I completely missed that you could re-arrange it like that, I see that it does in fact expand to the original sum now!

Answer (score -1):

$P(\neg 6_1) = \frac{5}{6}$

$P(\neg 6_2) = \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2$

$P(6_2) = 1 - \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2$

$P(6_n) = 1 - \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^n$

From this point on, the decision might be arbitrary. What does highly probable mean to you, and how much of a risk-taker are you?

The generally acceptable probability that 9 out of 10 would consider as worthy of an attempt = $99$%.

$1 - \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^n \geq 99\%$

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the question?  It appears to be answering a related question.  Perhaps tie in your calculations to expectation, as in the original post.

Comment: $E(X) = P(6_1) \cdot 1 + P(6_2) \cdot 2 + P(6_3) \cdot 3 + \dots$

Comment: I agree with the formula for the expectation, but the question appears to be about the recursive formula for the expectation, not about estimating the expectation.  Perhaps you could edit your answer to include the connection between your formula for the expectation and the recursive formula?